# Longest Substring without Repeating Characters Problem - Kotlin Recursion

Tags: algorithm, recursion, functional-programming, kotlin

I am practicing coding questions on leetcode. I have been an OOP my whole career, and I am trying to wade into the dark abyss that is functional programming. So I am trying to do things purely functional, e.g. using recursion to try to get to the answer. The problem statement is this: `Given a string, find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters.`

Sorry for asking literally this leetcode question that everybody else is asking :D

I have coded up this solution -

```
class Solution {
    fun lengthOfLongestSubstring(str: String): Int {
        return when {
            str.length == 1 -> 1
            str.isEmpty() -> 0
            else -> helper(str, 0, 1, 0)
        }
    }

    private tailrec fun helper(str: String, leftIndex: Int, rightIndex: Int, max: Int): Int {
        return when {
            rightIndex >= str.length+1 -> max
            rightIndex >= str.length && isDistinct(str.substring(leftIndex)) ->
                helper(str, leftIndex, rightIndex + 1, max(rightIndex - leftIndex, max))
            isDistinct(str.substring(leftIndex, rightIndex)) ->
                helper(str, leftIndex, rightIndex + 1, max(rightIndex - leftIndex, max))
            else -> helper(str, leftIndex + 1, leftIndex + max + 1, max)
        }
    }

    private fun isDistinct(substring: String): Boolean {
        return substring.toList().distinct().size == substring.length
    }
}
```

I have a couple specific questions - 
I am using the sliding window approach, is that appropriate in a functional setting? If not, what is a better approach functionally, speaking.

Is there redundancy in my recursion function that I can get rid of?

What things can I do to improve the legibility of the function? Clean code is always best!

What further steps can I take to optimize the solution? Currently this solution is only faster than 10% of other solutions (though those are likely imperative solutions)

Any other tips you can provide outside of the bounds of my question that can help would be awesome. I am also brand new to kotlin programming.

I don't necessarily hate this solution, but I'm sure it can be better. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, I don't think about performance, only about kotlin.

## Iluminate branch

in your when, you check if the `rightIndex >= string.length+1`.
this means in the next branches the size is maximal `string.length`.
Substring is exclusive, so it allows str.length.
this means the second and third branches are identical.

## Use Set

It would make more sense to me to use `toSet` instead of `toList.distinct`, because sets are meant to hold distinct versions.

## personal Choices:

#### Single-expression function

A [single-expression-function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#single-expression-functions) is a function with one expression .
In kotlin, you can write this in an easier way.
Instead of writing

```
fun lengthOfLongestSubstring(str: String): Int {
    return when {
        ...
    }
}
```

you can write

```
fun lengthOfLongestSubstring2(str: String): Int = when {
    ...
}
```

or even without return-type:

```
fun lengthOfLongestSubstring2(str: String) = when {
    ...
}
```

I personally like to write these like:

```
fun helper(
    str: String,
    leftIndex : Int,
    rightIndex : Int,
    max: Int
) = when {
    ...
}
```

#### function with receiver

If I'm right functional means:

- The function knows about the type and the type doesn't know about the function
- If a function receives the same input, it should return the same output

(or only the later)

The first way is often expressed by having a function that only takes parameters, but is not called on an object: `b(a)` instead of `a.b()`

Kotlin allows to let a function like `b(a)` look like `a.b()`, if you define it that way.   This is called a [function with receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver).
Note, inside de function-body, you refer to the receiver using `this`.

```
isDistinct("hi")
private fun isDistinct(
    substring: String
): Boolean = substring.toSet().size == substring.length
```

can be rewritten to

```
"hi".isDistinct()
private fun String.isDistinct() : Boolean = this.toSet().size == this.length
```

And as you don't have to call `this` inside a scope:

```
"hi".isDistinct()
private fun String.isDistinct() : Boolean = toSet().size == length
```

Or just:

```
"hi".isDistinct()
private fun String.isDistinct() = toSet().size == length
```

Under the scenes it's still the same function.
Inside kotlin, you can't call it the old way anymore

## New code

```
class Solution {
    fun lengthOfLongestSubstring(
        str: String
    ) = when {
        str.length == 1 -> 1
        str.isEmpty() -> 0
        else -> helper(str, 0, 1, 0)
    }

    private tailrec fun helper(
        str: String,
        leftIndex: Int,
        rightIndex: Int,
        max: Int
    ): Int = when {
        rightIndex >= str.length + 1 -> max
        str.substring(leftIndex, rightIndex).isDistinct() ->
            helper(str, leftIndex, rightIndex + 1, max(rightIndex - leftIndex, max))
        else -> helper(str, leftIndex + 1, leftIndex + max + 1, max)
    }

    private fun String.isDistinct() = toSet().size == length
}
```

Comment: Wow, great answer! I learned more about kotlin coding techniques and reduced the redundancy of my function. Thank you :)